# Displaying Form details in slickgrid on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, slickgrid

In my JSP page I have a form with many details to be entered, once the user click the submit then I want to display the results in a grid below the form as an item.

I am fetching each details using JSP Scriptlet and assigning it to slickgrid, here is the code for doing that

```
<script>
        var grid;
        dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
        var columns = [
            {id: "SlNo", name: "SlNo", field: "SlNo"},
            {id: "ItemName", name: "ItemName", field: "ItemName"},
            {id: "PartNo", name: "PartNo", field: "PartNo"},
            {id: "BatchNo", name: "BatchNo", field: "BatchNo"},
            {id: "UnitRate", name: "UnitRate", field: "UnitRate"},
            {id: "Quantity", name: "Quantity", field: "Quantity"},
            {id: "Discount", name: "Discount", field: "Discount"},
            {id: "NetAmount", name: "NetAmount", field: "NetAmount"},
            {id: "TaxRate", name: "TaxRate", field: "TaxRate"},
            {id: "TaxAmount", name: "TaxAmount", field: "TaxAmount"},
            {id: "TotalAmount", name: "TotalAmount", field: "TotalAmount"}
        ];
        var options = {
            enableCellNavigation: true,
            enableColumnReorder: false
        };           
        grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);            
        dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            grid.updateRowCount();
            grid.render();
        });
        dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
            grid.render();
        });
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
            var data = [];
            var i=0;
        <%ERPConnectionManager erpConn = (ERPConnectionManager) session.getAttribute("erpCon");
            ConfirmFunction(request, erpConn);
            ArrayList<SalesRecCdty> listSalesRec = (ArrayList<SalesRecCdty>) session.getAttribute("listval");
            Iterator itrn = listSalesRec.iterator();
            while (itrn.hasNext()) {
                SalesRecCdty salesrec = (SalesRecCdty) itrn.next();
                String itemName = salesrec.getCommName().toString();
                String partNo = "";
                String batchNo = salesrec.getBatchNo();
                String unitRate = String.valueOf(salesrec.getUnitrate());
                String quanity = String.valueOf(salesrec.getReqQty());
                String discount = String.valueOf(salesrec.getDiscount());
                String netAmount = String.valueOf(salesrec.getNetValue());
                String taxRate = String.valueOf(salesrec.getTaxpercent());
                String taxAmount = String.valueOf(salesrec.getTaxtotal());
                String totAmount = String.valueOf(salesrec.getTotalvalue());
        %>
                data[i]={
                    SlNo: i+1,
                    ItemName:"<%= itemName%>",
                    PartNo:"<%= partNo%>",
                    BatchNo:"<%= batchNo%>",
                    UnitRate:"<%= unitRate%>",
                    Quantity:"<%= quanity%>",
                    Discount:"<%= discount%>",
                    NetAmount:"<%= netAmount%>",
                    TaxRate:"<%= taxRate%>",
                    TaxAmount:"<%= taxAmount%>",
                    TotalAmount:"<%= totAmount%>"
                };  
                i++;
        <%
            }
        %>
                // grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
                dataView.beginUpdate();
                dataView.setItems(data);
                dataView.endUpdate();
            });
            e.preventDefault();   
            var ajaxdata = $('#cbobxOffice').val();   

            $.ajax({     
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {     
                }
            });
    </script>
```

I am able to fetch the data to the data array.. but the rows are not displayed in the grid, please help

Comment: @ghiscoding Thanks for correcting my mistakes. I was in a hurry

Comment: welcome, sorry I can't help with your problem though, I use PHP instead

Comment: @ghiscoding its ok. I got it corrected. I just loded the grid in a new page and used <iframe> to display it. It worked perfectly as i needed